# How to start behavior offset by C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

in XAML

```
<Image x:Name="ToolkitLogo" Source="Assets/1.jpg" Height="100" Width="100" >
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:Offset x:Name="Offset"
         OffsetX="150.96"
         OffsetY="0"
         Duration="3960.33"
         Delay="0"
         AutomaticallyStart="True"/>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

I can start the animation using XAML code `AutomaticallyStart = true`. But why can't I start it using C#? The error tells me I can't use it like a method

```
private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Offset.AutomaticallyStart(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Offset.StartAnimation()
```

Is what you want if you want to manually trigger the behavior in code behind.